# How do I keep an association table where multiple instances of the same relationship exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In a database that stores information about computers and related hardware, I want to keep a record of the ram sticks in the computer.  Each computer has a serial as the primary key.  I want to create a third table that associates ram sticks to computer serials.

computers

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| serial | brand  |  model  |
+--------+--------+---------+
| abc    | Dell   | 180     |
| def    | Dell   | 720     |
| xyz    | Lenovo | YogaMat |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

ram_sticks

```
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+
| ram_id |  DIMM  | Size | DDR  | Speed |
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+
|      1 | DIMM   | 2048 | DDR2 |  6400 |
|      2 | DIMM   | 1024 | DDR2 |  6400 |
|      3 | SODIMM | 2048 | DDR2 |  5300 |
+--------+--------+------+------+-------+
```

computers_ramsticks

```
+--------+--------+
| serial | ram_id |
+--------+--------+
| abc    |      1 |
| abc    |      1 |
| xyz    |      3 |
| xyz    |      3 |
+--------+--------+
```

How do I handle multiple instances of the same relationship?  It will often be the case that a single computer can have multiple identical sticks of ram.  I cannot reliably guess how many ram slots will be in each computer.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices, basically.  If all "ram_id"s are the same, you could add a count to the association table.  Then your "insert" would use `on duplicate key update` to increment the count, if the record already exists.  And your "delete" would decrement the count.

I would be more likely to take the second approach.  This would add a separate row for each ram id.  I would include additional columns in the table:

- Auto-generated unique id
- Date created (presumably the "install" date)

And perhaps other information would be appropriate, such as the slot.